# Assignment in function call

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am unused to the following notation used in an example for d3.js:

```
function dragged(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = event.x).attr("cy", d.y = event.y);
}
```

[Source](https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-dragging-i)

How is the assignment `d.x = event.x` called? I assume that this is an expression that evaluates to `event.x` but also assigns the value to `d.x`. How is this called in JavaScript? I would like to read more about it in the documentation but can't find that concept there.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators. Specifically the [Return value and chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Return_value_and_chaining) section

Comment: That's an **assignment expression**